# The "$$" math display syntax is broken by the "\$" escape sequence

Tags: support, mathjax

Pretty simple bug. If you try to type a full displaymath equation on another site, you would normally start it with `$$`.

This doesn't work this site, because the site interprets it as `\$ $`. Thus, the opening dollar sign is rendered into the equation, and the closing dollar sign is left off. It's also not displayed as full-size math. This is how it renders:

\$$\mbox{math}\$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\$\mbox{math}\$
```

renders as

\$\mbox{math}\$

---

```
$$\mbox{math}$$
```

renders as

$$\mbox{math}$$

---

In Chrome, they both look correct to me. Are you sure it isn't just a typo?

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. An escape character was added to P.SE's MathJax, and I assumed it applied to `$$` as well. My apologies!

Comment: @Emrakul I made the same mistake at first, trying to use `\$\$` as an escape sequence. But that's actually an empty regular MathJax snippet, so I ended up with a post with bare MathJax codes, which due to MathJax's forgiveness, got half-rendered. Very confusing.