# Change MathJax delimiter

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

The discussion [What should the MathJax delimiter be?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/167/228) seems to have a clear answer: the community would prefer `$` to the current `\$`. I'm therefore formally proposing this as a request to the site administrators.

Comment: Current status on this: Will Probably Be Changed™.

Answer (score 4):

Both delimiters (`$` and `\$`) are now active, until existing comments and posts can be cleaned up to use `$` only.

**Update Jun 21 2014:** All 37 comments with the old syntax have been edited (thanks Tim Stone for updating the Data Explorer with Puzzling!). All that's left is questions and answers now. [There are only 70 of them, and you can help edit!](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/203286) (Please only do so if you have edit privileges; avoid flooding the edit queue with suggestions that just change the delimiter.) If there are multiple issues with the posts that you are editing, fix them as well!

**Update Jun 23 2014**: All 70 posts with the old syntax have been edited. I have requested that the delimiter now be changed to only `$`. Thanks to all who helped with the cleanup!

Comment: I'll help with that cleanup. I've been horrible with the `\$` notation too, especially because my keyboard's \ key is _really_ jumpy and likes to insert 2 or 3 of them at once.

Comment: Isn't that a simple case of search and replace in the database? `s/\\\$/\$/g`?

Comment: @JoeZ. Ping, you can help now ;)

Comment: Whoops. I mostly was fixing my own posts and posts involved with the questions I answered.